# Array only printing last value

Tags: php, loops

Consider the following php code which is scraping a clients old static website for his customers emails...

```
$urls = explode(PHP_EOL, file_get_contents('urls.txt'));

print '<pre>'; print_r($urls); print '</pre>';

print '<strong>Results:</strong><br>';

function get_emails($url) {
    $html = file_get_contents($url);
    
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    @$dom->loadHTML($html);
    $links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

    foreach ($links as $link){
        $href = $link->getAttribute('href');
        if (strpos($href, 'mailto') !== false) {
            return str_replace("mailto:","",$href) . '<br>';
        }
    }
}
    
foreach ($urls as $key => $url) {
  print get_emails($url);
}
```

I am reading a list of urls from urls.txt but the result is only the one of the last url in the file.  All of the others are ignored. I had hoped it would return a nice list of all his customers urls so we can import them into the new site.

Can someone help diagnose the issue?

Comment: why are you returning in a foreach loop? Echo ...

Comment: Just updated it to echo, the same thing is still happening - only getting the last result

Comment: then only one thing in your array matches your if statement, comment out the if statment and try with echo :)

Comment: Tried that, and if i only put each url into urls.txt one at a time, i get a result for each, so the script works for individual urls, but only coughs up the last result if they are outputted as an array

Comment: hm, can you var_dump your array and edit the question with the output?

Comment: I have rollback the edits because the subsequent edits have rendered the accepted answer senseless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of:-

```
return str_replace("mailto:","",$href) . '<br>';
```

It will terminate the execution of loop.

***1. Either do:-***

```
$urls = explode(PHP_EOL, file_get_contents('urls.txt'));

print '<pre>'; print_r($urls); print '</pre>';

print '<strong>Results:</strong><br>';

function get_emails($url) {
    $html = file_get_contents($url);

    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    @$dom->loadHTML($html);
    $links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

    foreach ($links as $link){
       $href = $link->getAttribute('href');
       echo str_replace("mailto:","",$href) . '<br>';
    }
}

foreach ($urls as $key => $url) {
  get_emails($url);
}
```

***2. OR do like below:-***

```
$urls = explode(PHP_EOL, file_get_contents('urls.txt'));

print '<pre>'; print_r($urls); print '</pre>';

print '<strong>Results:</strong><br>';

function get_emails($url) {
    $html = file_get_contents($url);
    $data = array(); //define array
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    @$dom->loadHTML($html);
    $links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

    foreach ($links as $link){
        $href = $link->getAttribute('href');
        $data[] = str_replace("mailto:","",$href) . '<br>'; //assign  each value to the array

    }
   return $data;
}

foreach ($urls as $key => $url) {
  print_r(get_emails($url));
}
```

Comment: Just tried that, still getting the same results :-( - plus the termination would mean i only get the first result? Im only getting the last result at the moment

Comment: Option 1 returned only the last result, and option 2 didnt return anything. Hmm, i think you're onto something though, it looks like i may be overwriting a variable with each loop, which is why only the last shows

Comment: With option 2, i get this result in the print_r... Array ( ) Array ( [0] => Info@mysite.com
)

Comment: @Collins  can you show me the output of `print_r($links);`  ? put it just after `$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');` and check and show me the output of it?

Comment: Odd, its now decided to start working using option 1. Thank you for your help, thats a bit of a head scratcher!

Comment: @Collins  it will work for the second option too. check now

Comment: Wahey! Just added the list and boom, there they all are! Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Collins  glad to help you :):)